# Direct Memory Updates to Apache Ignite

Tags: ignite, dma

We use Apache Ignite to update prices of stocks continuously. Since these prices are stored in RAM in Ignite, is there some way to determine the memory address of a specific stock price, and update that address directly? That way we can bypass the indexing, query parsing, etc, and update Ignite much faster! We have enough RAM to keep entire DB in the memory.

Comment: Obviously, we still need to respect locks, etc - so that the integrity of queries is not compromised. And none of the data updated forms part of any index. And no rows are ever deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The way to update a single column in a record is to use an [entry processor](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/distributed-computing/collocated-computations#entry-processor). There's no way to directly get a memory address.

Comment: I get that there isn’t a way to do this currently. But is there anything about the way Ignite works, that makes such updates impossible? This is open source code, is it possible to change the code to support such a feature, for instance?

Comment: I mean, it's software so it's _possible_ but it's certainly non-trivial. You can't necessarily assume that the data is in memory for one thing, since Ignite supports persistence.